# Simple iteration method problem

Tags: numerical-methods

I have one math problem to solve here, but I don't have a clue how to do it.  I need to solve the equation $$\sin x-\frac x 2=0$$ by the simple iteration method.

Comment: What is the simple iteration method? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to find a solution in mathway... but there is nothing about the simple iteration method there... As I said I have no idea how to solve it :(

Comment: A search of the internet for "simple iteration method" turns up [these instructions](http://mpec.sc.mahidol.ac.th/numer/STEP9x.HTM), which should be good enough, although they are written a bit inside out.

Comment: It does not seems to work for me, but thank you for the time you spent on trying to help me :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say it does not work for you? Have you tried different initial values? This method is a bit on the touchy side (which is likely why it's not used so much)!

Comment: The simple iteration method is for solving equations of the form $x = \phi(x)$. (The cited web page doesn't make that completely clear.) In this case the equation is $x = 2\sin x$, and one iterates $2\sin x$ on an initial guess. One can get a good enough guess by examining a graph.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^*$ is a solution, then $x^* = 2 \sin x^*$. Hence, the simplest iteration method is
$$
x_{n+1} = 2 \sin x_n
$$
Taking $x_0=1$ works fine for me and I get $x^* \approx 1.895494267034$.
(Try $x_0=4$ for a surprise.)

There are only two other solutions: $x^*=0$ and $x^* \approx -1.895494267034$.

[image]

(picture by [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+x%3D2sin%20x))

Comment: What is good about this answer(or bad?) that it exploits the structure of the specific problem at hand, instead of just relying on continuity.

Answer (score 0):

I try plugging in some values. 0 obviously solves the equation. But to illustrate the iteration method, let´s use the unique positive solution. When I plug in 1/2 I get 0.23 (i.e. a number greater than 0) when I plug in 3 I get -1.36. By Intermediate value theorem the function must attain a zero between those points. So let´s plug in a midpoint, 7/4 after plugging it in I get 0.11, that number is closer to the one I got when I plugged in 1/2 so now I will look at a midpoint of 7/4 and 1/2 and so on...